# Transform an image A to an image B using the calculated SIFT keypoints in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, sift

is there a possibility to transform an image A to an image B using the calculated SIFT transforms? 
What I'm looking for is a function like "transform_using_sift" which works as follows:

```
[fa, da] = vl_sift (A);
[fb, db] = vl_sift (B);
B_from_A = transform_using_sift(A, fa, da, fb, db);
```

where B_from_A is the prediction of B using sift of B.

Comment: Have a look at [imtransform](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imtransform.html)

Comment: You can use SIFT to ascertain a relationship x = Ax' between matching point-pairs. Have a look at the [Direct linear Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_linear_transformation). Also, the vlfeat website contains an image stitching demo.